# php artisan migrate = connection refused (mac/laravel/xampp)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

so I'm getting this error when trying to run php artisan migrate on my newly created laravel project:

```
    Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = laravel-social and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:671
    667|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    668|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    669|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    670|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 671|             throw new QueryException(
    672|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    673|             );
    674|         }
    675|
```

I have googled extensively and while finding similar errors and trying to change things, I could not resolve my issue.. some information that might help and the things I have tried so far:

- I'm on a mac
- I'm using Xampp
- I had made sure I had started MySQL on Xampp before running the command
- I had changed my DB_HOST from 127.0.0.1 to localhost on my .env file, cleared cache and tried again, it didn't work (it did give me an error of no such file or directory though) I had also changed that on the database.php
- I had created the database "laravel-social" on phpMyAdmin
- I had confirmed the port, database username and password (it is root with no password, I had tried using one though, but the error was the same, so I returned back for the sake of debugging)
- This is a newly created project, so I'm not migrating a project from Windows or somewhere else
- Funny thing is that with or without Xampp started, I get this same error. Maybe something there?

.env file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel-social
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Are **all** your DB settings in the ```.env``` and are they correct?

Comment: Hi @Drk, I added my .env file on the topic. I have confirmed the database name, username and password, and also as I mentioned, tried to put localhost instead of 127.0.0.1 (also changing on database.php to match), but no luck, is there a way to see if those settings are actually correct or if maybe they are not? I just looked it up manually from my settings, like going to phpMyAdmin, etc.

Comment: Assuming the settings are correct, all seems fine! Do they match in ```config/database.php```? Does the query run successfully in mysql console? ```select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = laravel-social and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE';```

Comment: hmm interesting, taking that query and running it on mysql gives me: #1054 - Unknown column 'laravel' in 'where clause', what could that mean? It does look a bit unrelated to the connection refused error though, doesn't it?

Comment: Issue is with the hyphen in your database name. Can you try to use an *underscore* in the database name:  Change ```laravel-social``` to **```laravel_social```**

Comment: I changed it to laravelsocial and it returns the same error, but with the new name: #1054 - Unknown column 'laravelsocial' in 'where clause'.

Comment: Ooh! Try to change the query in the console and see if this runs:
```select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = "laravelsocial" and table_name = "migrations" and table_type = 'BASE TABLE';```

Comment: Also, add the version of Laravel and MySQL to the question.

Comment: the changed query ran fine (it returned 0 results, but no errors), Laravel Framework 7.17.2 and Server version: 10.4.13-MariaDB - Source distribution (hmm I'm wondering if this has something to do with MariaDB?).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216810/discussion-between-drk-and-displayname).

Comment: no luck so far... I'm wondering if this is due to my local project trying to communicate with Xampp's MySql. I've noticed that I can access Xampp via IP: "192.XX.XX.XX", I tried using that on .env and the database.php config file, and I get the error that MySQL has gone away... So far I have 3 different errors: 127.0.0.1 = connection refused, localhost = path does not exist, 192.X.X.X = mysql has gone away...

Comment: Let ```DB_HOST=127.0.0.1``` and [make this change in your mysql config file](https://medium.com/@panjeh/laravel-sqlstate-hy000-2002-connection-refused-within-mac-os-1959b81f3c4b "See if this helps")

Comment: Ok, so, although I have found a solution for myself, it was more of an alternative really. I didn't have MySQL installed on my mac as I was using the one from Xampp and I thought I should be able to connect to it. By installing MySQL from my machine, I was able to run the command and the .env file worked just as it was. However, I wanted to be able to connect to my Xampp's setup, so I actually couldn't solve the original problem. I shouldn't have 2 separate MySQL installations on my machine?

Comment: @Drk my conf file didn't have that line: !includedir /usr/local/etc/my.cnf.d

Comment: Wow! Great you got a solution!